# HTML source code with unicode will not display in C# webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

My code generates an html document which is displayed in the c# webbrowser control for a project of mine.  I have text in a number of different languages and have had zero problem until yesterday.

The following html document will display just fine in IE, Edge, or Chrome.  But it will be garbage in the c# webbrowser control.

In webbrowser it shows a dash or two for each line. I tried to paste a picture, but I'm not allowed to.  If I create a codeblock, it show the html text.  Here's a sample I had to type.

2  -

3  -

In any of my browsers (a sample line):
1 သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​ခ​ရစ်​၏​ဆွေ​တော်​စဉ်​မျိုး​တော်​ဆက် (လု၊ ၃:၂၃-၃၈။)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Here is the html:

```
<html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><style>body {font-family:"Arial Unicode MS",Verdana,Arial;}</style><body><meta charset='utf-8'><h1><center>&#4121;&#4159;&#4146; 1</center></h1><table><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v1">1 သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​ခ​ရစ်​၏​ဆွေ​တော်​စဉ်​မျိုး​တော်​ဆက် (လု၊ ၃:၂၃-၃၈။)</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v1">1 အာ​ဗြ​ဟံ​နှင့်​ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​မှ​ဆင်း​သက်​တော်​မူ​သော သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​ခ​ရစ်​၏​ဆွေ​တော်​စဉ်​မျိုး​တော်​ဆက် စာ​ရင်း​ကား​ဤ​သို့​တည်း။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v2">2 အာ​ဗြ​ဟံ​၏​သား​သည်​ဣ​ဇာက်၊ ဣ​ဇာက်​၏​သား​မှာ​ယာ​ကုပ်၊ ယာ​ကုပ်​၏​သား​များ​ကား​ယု​ဒ​နှင့်​ညီ​များ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v3">3 ယု​ဒ​နှင့်​တာ​မာ​မှ​ရ​သော​သား​များ​သည်​ဖာ​ရက် နှင့်​ဇာ​ရ၊ ဖာ​ရက်​၏​သား​မှာ​ဟေ​ဇ​ရုံ၊ ဟေ​ဇ​ရုံ ၏​သား​ကား​အာ​ရံ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v4">4 အာ​ရံ​၏​သား​သည်​အ​မိ​န​ဒပ်၊ အ​မိ​န​ဒပ်​၏​သား မှာ​နာ​ရှုန်၊ နာ​ရှုန်​၏​သား​ကား​စာ​လ​မုန်​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v5">5 စာ​လ​မုန်​နှင့်​ရာ​ခပ်​မှ​ရ​သော​သား​သည်​ဗော​ဇ၊ ဗော​ဇ နှင့်​ရု​သ​မှ​ရ​သော​သား​မှာ​ဩ​ဗက်၊ ဩ​ဗက်​၏​သား သည်​ယေ​ရှဲ၊ ယေ​ရှဲ​၏​သား​ကား​ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​မင်း​တည်း။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v6">6 ဉ​ရိ​ယ​၏​ဇ​နီး​နှင့်​ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​မင်း​ရ​သော​သား​သည် ရှော​လ​မုန်​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v7">7 ရှော​လ​မုန်​၏​သား​သည်​ရော​ဗောင်၊ ရော​ဗောင်​၏​သား မှာ​အ​ဘိ​ယ၊ အ​ဘိ​ယ​၏​သား​ကား​အာ​သ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v8">8 အာ​သ​၏​သား​သည်​ယော​ရှ​ဖတ်၊ ယော​ရှ​ဖတ်​၏​သား မှာ​ယ​ဟော​ရံ၊ ယ​ဟော​ရံ​၏​သား​ကား​ဩ​ဇိ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v9">9 ဩ​ဇိ​၏​သား​သည်​ယော​သံ၊ ယော​သံ​၏​သား​မှာ အာ​ခတ်၊ အာ​ခတ်​၏​သား​ကား​ဟေ​ဇ​ကိ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v10">10 ဟေ​ဇ​ကိ​၏​သား​သည်​မ​နာ​ရှေ၊ မ​နာ​ရှေ​၏​သား မှာ​အာ​မုန်၊ အာ​မုန်​၏​သား​ကား​ယော​ရှိ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v11">11 ဗာ​ဗု​လုန်​မြို့​သို့​ဣသ​ရေ​လ​အ​မျိုး​သား​တို့​အား ဖမ်း​ဆီး​ခေါ်​ဆောင်​သွား​ချိန်​၌ ယော​ရှိ​ရ​သော သား​များ​ကား​ယေ​ခေါ​နိ​နှင့်​ညီ​များ​ဖြစ်​ကြ​၏။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v12">12 ဗာ​ဗု​လုန်​မြို့​သို့​ဣသ​ရေ​လ​အ​မျိုး​သား​တို့​ဖမ်း​ဆီး ခေါ်​ဆောင်​ခြင်း​ခံ​ရ​ပြီး​နောက်၊ ယေ​ခေါ​နိ​ရ​သော​သား သည်​ရှာ​လ​သေ​လ၊ ရှာ​လ​သေ​လ​၏​သား​မှာ​ဇေ​ရု​ဗ ဗေ​လ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v13">13 ဇေ​ရု​ဗ​ဗေ​လ​၏​သား​သည်​အ​ဗျုဒ်၊ အ​ဗျုဒ်​၏​သား​မှာ ဧ​လျာ​ကိမ်၊ ဧ​လျာ​ကိမ်​၏​သား​ကား​အာ​ဇော်​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v14">14 အာ​ဇော်​၏​သား​သည်​ဇာ​ဒုတ်၊ ဇာ​ဒုတ်​၏​သား​မှာ အာ​ခိမ်၊ အာ​ခိမ်​၏​သား​ကား​ဧ​လုဒ်​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v15">15 ဧ​လုဒ်​၏​သား​သည်​ဧ​လာ​ဇာ၊ ဧလာဇာ​၏​သား​မှာ မ​ဿန်၊ မ​ဿန်​၏​သား​ကား​ယာ​ကုပ်​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v16">16 ယာ​ကုပ်​၏​သား​သည်​မာ​ရိ​၏​ခင်​ပွန်း​ဖြစ်​သူ​ယော​သပ် ဖြစ်​၏။ မာ​ရိ​ကား​မေ​ရှိ​ယ​ဟု​ခေါ်​ဝေါ်​သ​မုတ်​ခြင်း ခံ​ရ​သော​သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​၏​မယ်​တော်​တည်း။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v17">17 သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​ခ​ရစ်​ဖွား​မြင်​တော်​မူ​ခြင်း (လု၊ ၂:၁-၇။)</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v17">17 သို့​ဖြစ်​၍​ဆွေ​တော်​စဉ်​မျိုး​တော်​ဆက်​များ​မှာ အာ​ဗြ​ဟံ​မှ​သည်​ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​မင်း​တိုင်​အောင်​တစ်​ဆယ့် လေး​ဆက်၊ ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​မင်း​မှ​သည်​ဣသ​ရေ​လ​အ​မျိုး​သား တို့​ဗာ​ဗု​လုန်​မြို့​သို့ ဖမ်း​ဆီး​ခေါ်​ဆောင်​ခြင်း​ခံ​ရ​ချိန် တိုင်​အောင်​တစ်​ဆယ့်​လေး​ဆက်၊ ဣသ​ရေ​လ​အ​မျိုး​သား တို့ ဗာ​ဗု​လုန်​မြို့​သို့​ရောက်​ရှိ​ချိန်​မှ​သည်​မေ​ရှိ​ယ ဖွား​မြင်​သည်​တိုင်​အောင်​တစ်​ဆယ့်​လေး​ဆက်​ဖြစ် သ​တည်း။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v18">18 သ​ခင်​ယေ​ရှု​ခ​ရစ်​ဖွား​မြင်​တော်​မူ​ပုံ​ကား​ဤ​သို့ တည်း။ မယ်​တော်​မာ​ရိ​နှင့်​ယော​သပ်​တို့​ထိမ်း​မြား​ရန် စေ့​စပ်​ကြောင်း​လမ်း​ထား​ပြီး​နောက်၊ ပေါင်း​သင်း​နေ​ထိုင် မှု​မ​ပြု​ရ​မီ​မာ​ရိ​သည်​သန့်​ရှင်း​သော​ဝိ​ညာဉ်​တော် ၏​တန်​ခိုး​အား​ဖြင့်​ပ​ဋိ​သေနန္ဓ​စွဲ​ကပ်​လေ​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v19">19 ယော​သပ်​သည်​စိတ်​သ​ဘော​ထား​မြင့်​မြတ်​သူ​ဖြစ် သည်​အ​လျောက်​မာ​ရိ​အား​အ​သ​ရေ​မ​ပျက်​စေ လို​သ​ဖြင့် သူ​နှင့်​စေ့​စပ်​ကြောင်း​လမ်း​ထား​မှု​ကို တိတ်​တ​ဆိတ်​ဖျက်​သိမ်း​ရန်​အ​ကြံ​ရှိ​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v20">20 ဤ​သို့​အ​ကြံ​ရှိ​နေ​စဉ်​သူ​သည်​ထာ​ဝ​ရ​ဘု​ရား ၏​ကောင်း​ကင်​တ​မန်​တစ်​ပါး​ကို​အိပ်​မက်​မြင်​မက်​၏။ ထို​ကောင်း​ကင်​တမန်​က ``ဒါ​ဝိဒ်​၏​သား​မြေး​ယော​သပ်၊ သင်​သည်​မာ​ရိ​အား​ဇ​နီး​အ​ဖြစ်​သိမ်း​ပိုက်​ရ​မည်​ကို မ​ကြောက်​နှင့်။ အ​ဘယ်​ကြောင့်​ဆို​သော်​သူ​၏​ဝမ်း​တွင် ရှိ​သော​ပ​ဋိ​သေနန္ဓ​ကား​သန့်​ရှင်း​သော​ဝိ​ညာဉ်​တော် ၏​တန်​ခိုး​တော်​အား​ဖြင့်​ရ​သော​ပ​ဋိ​သေနန္ဓ​ဖြစ်​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v21">21 သူ​သည်​သား​ယောက်ျား​ကို​ဖွား​မြင်​လိမ့်​မည်။ ထို သား​သည်​မိ​မိ​လူ​မျိုး​အား​အ​ပြစ်​မှ​ကယ်​တင် မည့်​အ​ရှင်​ဖြစ်​သော​ကြောင့်​သူ့​ကို​ယေ​ရှု​ဟု နာ​မည်​မှည့်​ရ​မည်'' ဟု​ဆို​၏။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v22">22 ဤ​အ​မှု​အ​ရာ​များ​မှာ​ပ​ရော​ဖက်​အား​ဖြင့် ထာ​ဝ​ရ​ဘု​ရား​ပေး​တော်​မူ​ခဲ့​သော​ဗျာ​ဒိတ် တော်​အ​တိုင်း​ဖြစ်​ပျက်​ခြင်း​ပင်​ဖြစ်​သ​တည်း။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v23">23 ဗျာ​ဒိတ်​တော်​ကား ``အ​ပျို​က​ညာ​သည်​ကိုယ်​ဝန် ဆောင်​၍​သား​ယောက်ျား​ကို​ဖွား​မြင်​လိမ့်​မည်။ ထို သား​ကို​ဧ​မာ​နွေလ ဟု​ခေါ်​ဝေါ်​သ​မုတ်​ကြ​လိမ့်​မည်'' ဟူ​၍​ဖြစ်​သ​တည်း။</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v24">24 သို့​ဖြစ်​၍​ယော​သပ်​သည်​အိပ်​ပျော်​ရာ​မှ​နိုး​သော အ​ခါ ထာ​ဝ​ရ​ဘု​ရား​၏​ကောင်း​ကင်​တ​မန်​အ​မိန့် ရှိ​ခဲ့​သည့်​အ​တိုင်း မာ​ရိ​အား​မိ​မိ​ဇ​နီး​အ​ဖြစ် သိမ်း​ပိုက်​လေ​၏။-</span><p></font></td></tr><tr><td><font size=4><span id="v25">25 သို့​ရာ​တွင်​သား​ယောက်ျား​ဖွား​မြင်​သည်​တိုင်​အောင် မာ​ရိ​နှင့်​ပေါင်း​သင်း​နေ​ထိုင်​မှု​ကို​မ​ပြု​ဘဲ​နေ​၏။ ထို​သား​ကို​ယေ​ရှု​ဟု​နာ​မည်​မှည့်​လေ​၏။</span><p></font></td></tr></table><p></font></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you upload the image and add a link of images? somebody will add them for you here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9B325A047A88650E!34816&authkey=!ANBihvAZzi9CiG8&ithint=folder%2chtml

Comment: There are three pictures: 1) Burmese, 2) Thai, and 3) English.
These is one text file: 1) Burmese.html.

You’ll notice in the pictures that the native language will be seen in several places on the right half of the screen.  Those are list boxes or text boxes.

Comment: Only the Burmese is not displaying on the left side (a tab with the webbrowser control).  Only the Burmese is not displaying.  Furthermore, I’ve been testing with the code for over year, and I’ve displayed dozens of other languages.  This is the first time a language would not display.  I’ve check the Sqlite db, and everything is there.  (Also, simply double-click the Burmese.html, and it will display just fine; and all I did was right-click on my c# webbrowser and copied the source.)

Comment: You’ll also notice in the html source that I also included (toward the top) some of the Unicode characters in the decimal format (&#1234;) to see if that were the problem.